# how to make alias work at runtime?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, alias

i know if i make alias earlier, i could put this alias defination in /etc/profile, but now i have no choice, since some build operation is just on progress. i can use alias wget='wget -c' on new bash, but it not works for the bash that is now in build operation, so is there any method that can make alias work for other opened bash?

maybe i can move /usr/bin/wget to /usr/bin/tmp/wget, and then create an sh file on /usr/bin/wget
and the content of this file is /usr/bin/tmp/wget $1

this works especially when there is only one variable, but if there are 2 or more variables, how can this script work?

or is there any better ways to make alias work, or other method which can make the same effect, just like that sh file(how to make change to this file to make it support more variables?)

Comment: More like `"$@"` -- adding quotes protects arguments that contain whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `"$@"` instead of `$1` which will copy all args, not just the first one.

Comment: +1. Better yet, `"$@"` (with double-quotes), so that whitespace and asterisks and whatnot will be preserved (rather than breaking things).

Comment: yes it does, and it does not depend on your distrib but on your shell, and it is supported by bash, which one are you using? (btw your question is tagged as centos and bash)

Answer (score 2):

You can add the line `continue = on` to the ~/.wgetrc. [See the docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Wgetrc-Commands.html) for more information.

If you want to set retry limit to 3, add `tries = 3` to the ~/.wgetrc

Comment: maybe i need more options, for example, the maximal retry time should be 20, then what i should put into .wgetrc?

Comment: does the options in .wgetrc works immediately? or it may work the next wget is invoked?

Comment: so is there any method which can change the runtime option, for example wget is just being blocked, now i want to tell timeout option, is that possible?

Comment: There is `wait = n` option in wgetrc, using that you can enforce a timeout per retry. I don't think there is a way to do this after wget starts execution (of course you can use `killall wget`).

Comment: killall is not allowed, this will make the system mess, with a uncompleted installation:(

Comment: Updating the *current* wget in progress is possible, but it would involve attaching a debugger to the running process and manipulating memory. Before you ask, I don't know the details of making it work.